# What's the true value of $\sqrt{(x ^ 2)}$ and ${({\sqrt{x}}) ^ 2}$

Tags: solution-verification, exponentiation, fake-proofs

## Background

I'm not completely sure if these rules can be applied outside $\mathbb{R}$, but let's assume real numbers only for the sake of simplicity.

We have [Exponent Properties](https://www.cuemath.com/algebra/exponent-rules/), which then can be extended to [Fractional Exponents](https://www.cuemath.com/algebra/fractional-exponents/).

Then we have [this](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-sqrt-x-2-x-absolute-value-while-sqrt-x-2-x) and [this](https://socratic.org/questions/58c117ccb72cff2018c2a5ce) statements, which declare that:

$$_{(1)}\sqrt{(x ^ 2)} = |x|$$
$$_{(2)}{({\sqrt{x}}) ^ 2} = x$$

### Problem

Assuming all of the above is correct, then any of the following procedures would be valid to counter-argument aforementioned statements: By following exponent properties, and/or then finding a connection between above both (seemingly exclusive) sentences, we obtain:

$$_{(3)}\sqrt{(x ^ 2)} = {({x ^ 2}) ^ \frac{1}{2}} = {x ^ {2\frac{1}{2}}} = {x ^ \frac{2}{2}} = {x ^ 1} = x$$
$$_{(4)}\sqrt{(x ^ 2)} = \sqrt{(xx)} = \sqrt{x}\sqrt{x} = {(\sqrt{x}) ^ 2} = x |_{by (2)}$$

Personally, I find (4) to be more interesting since it clearly shows a connection between both cases, becoming valid to counter-argument (1) and (2) simultaneously, by following the chain of operations from either side.

On the other hand, I have the slight feeling that, since $\sqrt{x}$ can be both positive and negative (thus becoming $\pm\sqrt{x}$), maybe that has something to do with my point of view, yet one of my referenced sources explicitly state that $\sqrt{x}$, by convention, only picks the positive root; possibly I'm overlooking something else.

Given all of the above, the question is:

## What's the true value of $\sqrt{(x ^ 2)}$ and ${({\sqrt{x}}) ^ 2}$

### Edits

#### #0

Ironically enough, even before posting my question, reading through the info of [`fake-proofs`](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/fake-proofs/info) while tagging this answer of mine, I found a piece of valuable information to the question itself, specifically:

> An example of a fake proof is
> $$1=\sqrt{-1\cdot-1}=\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1}=i^2=-1$$
> which fails because $\sqrt{xy}=\sqrt x\sqrt y$ does not hold if $x$ or $y$ is negative.

However I will proceed by posting my question anyways: That way, It'll allow for more insight to be provided by others for future reference.

Comment: In Real Analysis, although the statement $\left(\sqrt{x}\right)^2 = x$ is correct for non-negative real numbers, the statement is **gibberish** (i.e. meaningless rather than false) for negative real numbers.

Comment: In Complex Analysis, the statement $\displaystyle \left(\sqrt{x}\right)^2 = x$ is accurate, even though the square root function is (itself) ambiguous.  For example, does $\displaystyle\sqrt{-1}$ refer to $(i)$ or $(-i)$?  So, in Complex Analysis, the statement $\displaystyle \sqrt{x^2}$ is ambiguous, while the statement $|x|$ represents the absolute value (or *norm*) function whose domain is the complex numbers and whose range is the non-negative real numbers.

Comment: @user2661923 $\sqrt{x^2}$ and $|x|$ aren't _statements_, they're _expressions_.

Comment: @J.G. Good point.  Unfortunately, editing time has elapsed on both of my comments.

Comment: I think all variations on $(x^a)^b$ have been thoroughly explored in earlier questions on this website, and I encourage Jebyte to do a search for them. I doubt anyone will come up with anything that hasn't already been posted here many times.